# How do you update an embedded assembly resource?

Tags: .net, embedded-resource

I'm trying to determine if there is a good way to update a resource that is embedded within an assembly.  For instance, say I have I text file embedded and I want to change the contents.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Looks like the following has a good example:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/ce28296f-e391-4df6-86fc-c289302c8482

Anyone have other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following looks like a good solution:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/ce28296f-e391-4df6-86fc-c289302c8482